# Error while configuring Ruby on Rails - pg_ext (LoadError) on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-8.1

This happens when I try to run my server.
[image: CMD Prompt Errors]

I cant find a solution online. Could anyone help me?

I am including the database file and the pgAdming application screenshot if it helps.

[image: database.yml]

[image: pgAdmin III]

Comment: did u try bundle update ? (save ur gemfile.lock before)

Comment: yes that fixed it! 
Pls  add an answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: but dont remove old gemfile.lock - bundle update sometimes broke any dependencies, and u mb have to fix some gem's versions, but it always easy to google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `bundle update` at ur ruby console